# Upload invoices to host and send url to customers! hide URL joomla?

Tags: url, joomla, module, hide

I don't know exactly what tittle use but my problem is as follows. I have a Website for my small company and i would love to upload all my invoices to my host (where my website is hosted) and send to my clients just a link for the invoice. But the problem is that when i send a link for example "www.mycompany.com/invoice/invoice-15.pdf" i need to send them that link but if some of my clients see the URL can easily change the invoice number in the URL and see other invoices which i don't want. That's is why I wonders if there is kind of module that hide the URL and display for example "www.mycompany.com/invoice/l87y23bf9.pdf". I don't know if its possible or if there is some other options which i can use.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very convenient to upload invoices by FTP. And download link is outside of Joomla. Even this one `www.mycompany.com/invoice/l87y23bf9.pdf` is not controlled by Joomla. If it would be something like `www.mycompany.com/index.php?option=com_cobalt&task=download&id=2` then you can control it.

i suggest you install extension like Cobalt. then you create article and upload file to that article. You set author of that article user you want to give invoice to. Then you set that only this user can open this article.

Another way is to install some PM (Personal Message) extension and send files internally as attachment to personal message.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is Joomla!, I recommend you this way to manage invoices, using extension to upload PDF invoice or any documents that you want to share with your customers

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jdownloads/

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/phoca-download/

Then, in your website, you open login panel for customers. So, when you send invoices or any document for your customers, just send customer login info on first time, them your customers can login and see it as private area. Two extensions above allow to set permission to view for special user(s), or publish file if you want to show for all customers.

It's good way that I'm using, anytime when you have new invoices or files, just alert your customers about file name via email, so customer can login and see, download, etc.